# PHP error control

Tags: php, error-handling, runtime-error

I have recently learned of the function error_get_last() and json_last_error(). Going through tutorials, I rarely found information on the functions above.

Will all errors caused by json_encode() or json_decode() not be in error_get_last() already?

Is there a better way to handle errors (and memory leaks) during runtime (just before output)?

I use a buffer to hold all output, use the functions above to check for errors, and output the data if no errors are found.

Comment: preg_last_error()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**error_get_last** returns PHP runtime type of errors, for example division by zero is such an error.

The errors returned by the functions **json_decode** and **json_encode** are not runtime errors.

Consider the following example to get better understanding:

```
json_decode('Hello world');
echo error_get_last() . PHP_EOL; // No error here
echo json_last_error() . PHP_EOL;  // Error #4 - JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
```

Comment: Are there more error functions like the two above? (Not considering mysql_error() in favor of PDO)

Comment: On looking through sites with php error function definitions, not one mentions json_last_error(). I am just wondering if i missed another function.